# How to edit magento code <!--[if <!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]> in version 1.8.0.0

Tags: magento-1.8, theme

I am unable to resolve this issue. My website www.cartdeal.com is showing `]>` at beginning of the webpage. I was struggling hard to find where this icon is coming from. Found the difference between my localhost website and live website. The difference is in the following line `<!--[if <!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]>`. Does anybody where this code is located in magento as i am unable to locate the code. I just need to edit the last two characters to get rid of this problem.

I have tried and edit the page.xml file

```
            <!-- Add stylesheets with no media queries for use in IE 8 and below -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie8.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[ (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile)]]></if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland-ie8.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[ (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile)]]></if></action>

            <!-- Add stylesheets with media queries for use by modern browsers -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!--><]]></if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
```

But the same is code is working on my localhost and showing ]> tag on live server.

**EDIT**

In addition to this, when i click the 'View page source' button, i see that there are some changes in the source code that is appearing on my localhost and live magento hosting on godaddy.

On Localhost the code is

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cart Deal</title>
<meta name="description" content="Online Shopping of Apparels, Men &amp; Women Clothing, Footwear &amp; Accessories. Electronic &amp; Mobile Store." />
<meta name="keywords" content="Apparel, Clothing, Mobile" />
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://127.0.0.1/magento/media/favicon/default/logo1.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://127.0.0.1/magento/media/favicon/default/logo1.png" type="image/x-icon" />`

Whereas on live magento it is

`<html style="" id="top" class=" js no-touch localstorage" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Cart Deal</title>
<meta name="description" content="Online Shopping of Apparels, Men &amp; Women Clothing, Footwear &amp; Accessories. Electronic &amp; Mobile Store.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Apparel, Clothing, Mobile">
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">
<link rel="icon" href="http://cartdeal.com/media/favicon/websites/1/cart.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartdeal.com/media/favicon/websites/1/cart.png" type="image/x-icon">`

I think the problem can be resolved by amending the live hosting code and replacing it with the same as appearing in the localhost. But unable to find the file where i can do the changes. How can i add 
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->`

above the head section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved. Although i think it is not perfect solution for a responsive theme but now it not showing the unwanted icon on top of webpage for now. By removing the `<if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!--><]]></if>` from the code and only using the action block to add css files.

Comment: Please accept your own answer then to mark the quesiton als resolved. This website is still in beta thus a answer rate of 80% is needed: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

What is contained between `<!-- -->` is interpreted by the browser as a comment. Even if it may be interpreted by some browsers differently the rule is the same "You cannot have a comment inside a comment".
So your line is interpreted like this:

```
<!--[if <!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]>
  |                                          ||  
  |                                          ||---output
  |--- comment start                         |--- comment end
```

That's why you see the `]>` at the top of the pages. It is interpreted as output.
The correct use of the `<if>` tags when adding stylesheets is this:

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_css</type>
    <name>css/styles-ie.css</name>
    <params/>
    <if>lt IE 8</if>
</action>
```

So you have to put only the condition inside the `<if>` tag. the comment tags will be added automatically by Magento in `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::getCssJsHtml`.
So try it like this:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name><params/><if>(gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)</if></action>
```

Comment: thanks Marius. I have tried amending the code with the above, but my webpage then is not able to pick any css files and shows the basic html page.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem but removing the condition is not the ideal solution.

I ended up finding that GT Speed module was the module causing the issue.

Here is the fix to apply under `app/code/community/GT/Speed/Block/Html/Head.php`

Replace line 59-61:

```
if ( !empty( $if ) ) {
     $html .= '<!--[if ' . $if . ']>' . "\n";
}
```

By:

```
        if (!empty($if)) {
            // open !IE conditional using raw value
            if (strpos($if, "><!-->") !== false) {
                $html .= $if . "\n";
            } else {
                $html .= '<!--[if '.$if.']>' . "\n";
            }
        }
```

And then line 76-77:

```
        if ( !empty( $if ) ) {
            $html .= '<![endif]-->' . "\n";
        }
```

By:

```
        if (!empty($if)) {
            // close !IE conditional comments correctly
            if (strpos($if, "><!-->") !== false) {
                $html .= '<!--<![endif]-->' . "\n";
            } else {
                $html .= '<![endif]-->' . "\n";
            }
        }
```

That'll fix the issue with GT Speed.

Ensure you don't have any CSS/JS minification/compression modules, that may be the cause of the issue.